# Create index on table with multi columns

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql, if i use this query frequently:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE key1=? AND key2=?
```

I want to create index on `student`, what is the main difference between these two below?

```
CREATE INDEX idx_key1 on student (key1);
CREATE INDEX idx_key2 on student (key2);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX idx_keys on student (key1, key2);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599773/oracle-single-multicolumn-index-or-two-single-column-indexes

Comment: This might help too: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/index-on-multiple-columns-for-sql-performance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one (`CREATE INDEX idx_keys on student (key1, key2)`) will return all the rows you need in a single index seek (to find the rows) + key lookups to get the columns.

If you create 2 single-column indexes, only one of them can be used for index seek. Then for every returned row you need a key lookup to get the other key and filter the results. Or the DB engine will simply decide it's faster to just do a table scan and filter.

So the 2nd one is much better for your query.